# Cannot Parse a JSON response that is received by RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I need to parse a JSON response that I receive from a web service but I am receiving following error message, I puzzled with the this. I tried it without Results class as well to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

**Code**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new 
                                        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        ResponseEntity<Results> responseEntity = restTemplate
                .getForEntity(
                        "http://primesport.sieenasoftware.com/QryApi
                         /GetEvents?
                         username=username&
                         password=password&
                         userid=23",
                         Results.class);
        System.err.println(">>" + responseEntity.getBody().getEvents().size());
```

**Classes**

**Results**

```
public class Results {
    private List<Events> events;
    getter and setter
}
```

**Events**

```
   public class Event {
       private long eventId;
       private String name;
       private String subTitle;
       private String description;
       private String localDate;
       private String localDateFrom;
       private String imageUrl;
       private int venueId;
       private String venue;
       private int availableTickets;
       private long performerId;
       private String performer;
       private String performerType;
       private int subcategoryId;
       private String urlCategoryName;
       private String metaTitle;
       private String metaDescription;
       private String primeSportUrl;
       private String sectionWiseView;
       private String venueCity;
       private String venueState;
       private String snippetDate;
       private int eiProductionId;
       private boolean requireBillingAsShipping;
    public long getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }
    public void setEventId(long eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSubTitle() {
        return subTitle;
    }
    public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getLocalDate() {
        return localDate;
    }
    public void setLocalDate(String localDate) {
        this.localDate = localDate;
    }
    public String getLocalDateFrom() {
        return localDateFrom;
    }
    public void setLocalDateFrom(String localDateFrom) {
        this.localDateFrom = localDateFrom;
    }
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
    public int getVenueId() {
        return venueId;
    }
    public void setVenueId(int venueId) {
        this.venueId = venueId;
    }
    public String getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }
    public void setVenue(String venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }
    public int getAvailableTickets() {
        return availableTickets;
    }
    public void setAvailableTickets(int availableTickets) {
        this.availableTickets = availableTickets;
    }
    public long getPerformerId() {
        return performerId;
    }
    public void setPerformerId(long performerId) {
        this.performerId = performerId;
    }
    public String getPerformer() {
        return performer;
    }
    public void setPerformer(String performer) {
        this.performer = performer;
    }
    public String getPerformerType() {
        return performerType;
    }
    public void setPerformerType(String performerType) {
        this.performerType = performerType;
    }
    public int getSubcategoryId() {
        return subcategoryId;
    }
    public void setSubcategoryId(int subcategoryId) {
        this.subcategoryId = subcategoryId;
    }
    public String getUrlCategoryName() {
        return urlCategoryName;
    }
    public void setUrlCategoryName(String urlCategoryName) {
        this.urlCategoryName = urlCategoryName;
    }
    public String getMetaTitle() {
        return metaTitle;
    }
    public void setMetaTitle(String metaTitle) {
        this.metaTitle = metaTitle;
    }
    public String getMetaDescription() {
        return metaDescription;
    }
    public void setMetaDescription(String metaDescription) {
        this.metaDescription = metaDescription;
    }
    public String getPrimeSportUrl() {
        return primeSportUrl;
    }
    public void setPrimeSportUrl(String primeSportUrl) {
        this.primeSportUrl = primeSportUrl;
    }
    public String getSectionWiseView() {
        return sectionWiseView;
    }
    public void setSectionWiseView(String sectionWiseView) {
        this.sectionWiseView = sectionWiseView;
    }
    public String getVenueCity() {
        return venueCity;
    }
    public void setVenueCity(String venueCity) {
        this.venueCity = venueCity;
    }
    public String getVenueState() {
        return venueState;
    }
    public void setVenueState(String venueState) {
        this.venueState = venueState;
    }
    public String getSnippetDate() {
        return snippetDate;
    }
    public void setSnippetDate(String snippetDate) {
        this.snippetDate = snippetDate;
    }
    public int getEiProductionId() {
        return eiProductionId;
    }
    public void setEiProductionId(int eiProductionId) {
        this.eiProductionId = eiProductionId;
    }
    public boolean isRequireBillingAsShipping() {
        return requireBillingAsShipping;
    }
    public void setRequireBillingAsShipping(boolean requireBillingAsShipping) {
        this.requireBillingAsShipping = requireBillingAsShipping;
    }

}
```

**Partial Response**

```
[{
"EventId":1000250537,
"Name":"US Open Golf",
"SubTitle":null,
"Description":"US Open Golf Tickets",
"Date":"\/Date(1434873560000)\/",
"LocalDate":"6/20/2015 11:59 PM",
"LocalDateFrom":null,
"ImageUrl":null,
"VenueId":146566,
"Venue":"Chambers Bay Golf Course",
"AvailableTickets":33,
"PerformerId":151551,
"Performer":"US Open Golf",
"PerformerType":"Golf",
"SubcategoryId":55,
"UrlCategoryName":"Sports",
"MetaTitle":null,
"MetaDescription":null,
"PrimeSportUrl":"http://primesport.sieenasoftware.com/e/sports/us-open-golf/chambers-bay-golf-course/",
"SectionWiseView":null,
"VenueCity":"UNIVERSITY PLACE",
"VenueState":"WA",
"SnippetDate":null,
"EIProductionId":99985,
"RequireBillingAsShipping":false},
{
"EventId":1000253479,
"Name":"Womens College World Series",
"SubTitle":null,
"Description": .....
```

**UPDATE**

I know JAXB can be used for both JSON and XML, I am trying to use it to see if it would help to solve the issue.

**UPDATE**

The code is returning following exception:

```
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.myproject.myevent.Results out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@dedcd10; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.myproject.myevent.Results out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@dedcd10; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:809)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:576)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:261)
    at com.myproject.service.TicketSeviceImpl.primeSport(TicketSeviceImpl.java:217)
    at com.myproject.service.TicketSeviceImpl.findTicket(TicketSeviceImpl.java:45)
    at com.myproject.web.TicketController.findTicket(TicketController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

**UPDATE**

following code returns

**Code**

```
try {
            System.err.println(">>> primeSport");
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(
                    new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            ResponseEntity<Event[]> responseEntity = restTemplate
                    .getForEntity(
                            "http://primesport.sieenasoftware.com/QryApi/GetEvents?username=username&password=password&userid=23",
                            Event[].class);
            System.err.println(">>" + responseEntity.getBody().length);
            System.err.println(">>" + responseEntity.getBody()[0].getEventId());
            System.err.println(">>" + responseEntity.getBody()[1].getEventId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Output**

```
>1532
>0
>0
```

Comment: Are you sure you request was syntactically correct? I'm pretty sure it isn't. Look more carefully at the api

Comment: The partial response that you have posted is not a valida json.

Comment: @muddyfish the request is correct, I think something is wrong with response,

Comment: @SandeepPoonia I know but not sure how to solve the issue.

Comment: @Jack I don't know whether it helps, but the JSON response has a "Date" field and he corresponding field doesn't exist in the Result class.

Comment: @Jack try to fetch the response directly using curl call or browser on path http://primesport.sieenasoftware.com/QryApi/GetEvents?username=username&password=password&userid=23 and verify you get proper json or not.

Comment: @KDM I changed that to date but still receive the same error message.

Comment: what is the request to your rest service?

Comment: @Jack I was mentioning that the JSON has an extra field "Date" which doesn't exist in the Result. And IMO they should all be Strings.

Comment: @kswaughs sampel request is provided.

Comment: @Jack I hope you got a solution. Else can you check whether changing `ResponseEntity<Results>` to `ResponseEntity<List<Event>>` helps?

Comment: @KDM thanks but what should I replace Results.class with?

Comment: @Jack if the error is gone, you can construct a new result object and set the events with responseEntity.getBody() - which should be List<Event>.

Comment: @jack it should be List.class I guess.

Comment: @KDM what do you mean could not solve it yet.

Comment: Turn your Spring logs to debug, they'll tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how to do that?

Comment: Add slf4j logging with an appropriate implementation, enable a spring logger, run your code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis does that show extra information to what I receive in stacktrace?

Comment: It'll print the exception message, which I dont see in your question. If you have it please post it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I see, will figure that out and add that to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for your suggestion I just updated the question with the exception.

Comment: Whats the reason for downvote? I am not that smart to take a correct guess. Be smart and clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following and see whether helps:

```
ResponseEntity<Events[]> responseEntity = restTemplate
            .getForEntity(
                    "http://primesport.sieenasoftware.com/QryApi
                     /GetEvents?
                     username=username&
                     password=password&
                     userid=23",
                     Events[].class);
System.err.println(">>" + responseEntity.getBody().length);
```

For mapping the fields to the JSON members you can use Jackson annotation `JSONProperty("EventId")` can be used for the `eventId` field. Similarly for others.

```
@JsonProperty("EventId")
private long eventId;
@JsonProperty("Name")
private String name;
```

Comment: responseEntity.getBody().length returns 1532
responseEntity.getBody()[0].getEventId() returns null

Comment: Does the number of entries match 1532? Isn't eventID a long? Check your POJO. I suspect you converted them to String (you mentioned somewhere). Please change them to match the JSON response.

Comment: They were all String I changed them to different types but I am still receiving zero.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but can you try changing `eventId` in the POJO to `EventId` and see whether it helps? And also check the setters/getters.

Comment: I changed eventId to EventId but still have the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the getter/setter/field declaration for eventId? And also confirm whether the total number of records returned is matching what is contained in the response.

Comment: I included a complete list of event class getters/setters, I am not receiving total number of events from server but I suppose that number is correct otherwise because it is always returning the same number and it is not null or zero.

Comment: @Jack what about the other fields? Like name for example?

Comment: @Jack see the update. Using annotations it might be possible to map your fields to the JSON structure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to see the exact request getting generated? Let's say in a proxy software like fiddler/charles?

Sometimes I have experienced, the framework adds additional constructs(encoding, etc), before the requests actually really gets to the wire(or reaching the server endpoint).

Try this, to create the request. Even the documentation for RestTemplate suggests to avoid double encoding for URL. It may not be very apparent when looking in the IDE.

```
String url = "http://primesport.sieenasoftware.com/QryApi/GetEvents?";
MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
params.add("username", "username");
params.add("password", "password");
params.add("userid", "23");

UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).queryParams(params).build();
System.out.println(uriComponents.toUri());
```

Please let me know, how it works out.

Also, please let know, if you cant find steps to setup fiddler proxy. It quite a handy tool, while coding the service clients.

Answer (score -1):

According to the json format, all you need is using the Event class instead of the Result class.
Or change the JSON result to this :

```
["events": {
"EventId":1000250537,
"Name":"US Open Golf",
"SubTitle":null,
"Description":"US Open Golf Tickets",
"Date":"\/Date(1434873560000)\/",
"LocalDate":"6/20/2015 11:59 PM",
"LocalDateFrom":null,
"ImageUrl":null,
"VenueId":146566,
"Venue":"Chambers Bay Golf Course",
"AvailableTickets":33,
"PerformerId":151551,
"Performer":"US Open Golf",
"PerformerType":"Golf",
"SubcategoryId":55,
"UrlCategoryName":"Sports",
"MetaTitle":null,
"MetaDescription":null,
"PrimeSportUrl":"http://primesport.sieenasoftware.com/e/sports/us-open-golf/chambers-bay-golf-course/",
"SectionWiseView":null,
"VenueCity":"UNIVERSITY PLACE",
"VenueState":"WA",
"SnippetDate":null,
"EIProductionId":99985,
"RequireBillingAsShipping":false},
{
"EventId":1000253479,
"Name":"Womens College World Series",
"SubTitle":null,
"Description": .....
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try importing Jackson Jar or add dependency in pom.xml if you are using Maven.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      try
      {
         mapper.writeValue(new File("c://temp/employee.json"), Results);
      }
```

Comment: I do not get you, which dependency? it does not show any dependency is missing. Also how can I use the code you suggested?